# Retornar valor igual entre duas listas usando a função preg_match no PHP

Tags: php

Olá, eu tenho duas listas e gostaria de saber como posso retornar os valores iguais entre os elementos dessas duas listas.

**Código:**

```
$lista1 = ["CURITIBA","SP","BH","RS"];
$lista2 = ["RJ","SC","AM","CURITIBA"];
$matches = array(); 

for($i=0;$i <= 3; $i++){

 $string = "$lista1[$i]";
 echo "Valor CMDB: $string"."</br>"; 
 $pattern = "/$lista2[$i]/";
 echo "Valor HUB: $pattern"."</br>";
 preg_match($pattern , $string, $matches);

 if(array_key_exists($i, $matches)){
    echo "Match: $matches[$i]"."</br>"."</br>"; 
 }else{
    echo "No Match"."</br>"."</br>"; 
 } 

}
```

Meu *if* está me retornando sempre *No Match*, acredito que seja por causa da ordem dos elementos, como posso fazer com que ele identifique os elementos iguais e me retorne eles em meu *echo*?

[Visualizar código online](https://ideone.com/7D1a3p)

Comment: A dúvida era referente a function preg_match(), porém o rray mostrou uma forma mais clara e objetiva, o POST é valido para qm tiver futuras dúvidas sobre essa função, no caso eu desconhecia a função array_intersect()

Comment: sim, a pergunta que citei apresenta justamente a solução que o rray postou aqui, pois são os mesmos problemas.

Comment: Entendi amigo, agradeço a todos pela atenção!